# Go - Best way to return package error based on string?

Tags: go, error-handling, package

I have a package with defined exported errors and a method that parses a string that can have error data. Is there a way to return the exported error that matches the string? Is it only possible with a `switch-case`?

```
package foobarbaz

/* Import */

var (
    ErrFoo = errors.New("foo")
    ErrBar = errors.New("bar")
    /* More... */
)

func ParseStringWithErr(s string) (string, error) {
    // Data looks like e.g. "data:foo"
    var result string
    var err error
    result = getResultAsString(s)
    err = errors.New(getErrAsString(s)) // Will be "foo", "bar", etc... as string
    
    return result, err  // DOESN'T WORK
                        // New error won't be equivalent to the exported Errors
}
```

It's actually slightly more complicated than this as the parsed values are then stored in an object which is then returned. It is possible that the string to be parsed doesn't contain error data in which case the getErrAsString portion is just not called (and the err retains its null value of `<nil>` which is correct).

Clearly, I can write a function that just switches on the error string but there are several exported errors and it seems weird to have to write a case for each one.

Answer (score 2):

Basically what you want is to lookup an `error` value from a string, from its error string.

Initialize and use a simple map for it:

```
var errMap = map[string]error{}

func init() {
    for _, err := range []error{ErrFoo, ErrBar} {
        errMap[err.Error()] = err
    }
}

func LookupError(s string) (err error, ok bool) {
    err, ok = errMap[s]
    return
}
```

Testing it:

```
err, ok := LookupError("foo")
fmt.Println(err, ok, err == ErrFoo)

err, ok = LookupError("bar")
fmt.Println(err, ok, err == ErrBar)

err, ok = LookupError("baz")
fmt.Println(err, ok)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0LM9GC9r1Q-)):

```
foo true true
bar true true
<nil> false
```